# xslt for substring before and using or condition

Tags: xslt, substring, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT.
The request is   100KV or 100MV or 100GV
i want to get the numbers so I am using which gives me expected result. But I have to compare the input can be "K", "M" or "G". I have tried choose and it works fine. But i have multiple places to do this transformation. Is there any better way than choose? by which i can do comparison in one xslt.

```
 <xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test='contains(//ns0:VALUE,"K")'> 
<tns:floatValue>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//ns0:VALUE,'K')"/>
 </tns:floatValue>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test='contains(//ns0:VALUE,"M")'> 
<tns:floatValue>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//ns0:VALUE,'M')"/>
 </tns:floatValue>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test='contains(//ns0:VALUE,"G")'> 
<tns:floatValue>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//ns0:VALUE,'G')"/>
 </tns:floatValue>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(translate(//ns0:VALUE, 'MG', 'KK'), 'K')"/>
```

So, translate M or G into K, and then just find the substring before K.

Alternatively, if you wanted to be really generic, and find the number before the first non-numeric character, you could do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//ns0:VALUE, substring(translate(//ns0:VALUE, '1234567890', ''), 1, 1))"/>
```

Do note, are you sure you mean to use `//ns0:VALUE` as this will always use the first occurence of `ns0:VALUE` in the XML if there happen to more than one?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will try the second option. Regarding //ns0:VALUE..i.e is just an example . The xpath is actually much longer than that.

Comment: Thanks Tim. the second option worked. I have similar issue with one more element the request will be same 100KV or 100MV or 100 GV.. i want to map "K","M" or "G". This statement helps me get that substring(translate(//ns0:VALUE, '1234567890', ''), 1, 1). But my issue is i also want to convert "K" to lowercase and keep others as it is.. i.e. expected output is "k", "M" "G"

Comment: Simply expand the translate to change the letter K to k; `substring(translate(//ns0:VALUE, 'K1234567890', 'k'), 1, 1)`